# Connect PIC programmer to Linux

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, linux, programmer

I have got a cheap USB PIC programmer but its CD has only drivers for windows is there ans way to work with it on ubuntu 14.04

[image: The programmer from back]

[image: AEI PIC Programmer]

Comment: Would help if you gave some details about exactly which cheap USB PIC programmer you have.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://usbpicprog.org/?page_id=193) for a USB PIC programmer that works on Ubuntu. If thats not the programmer you have the software won't work so you need to tell us which one you have.

Comment: It's AEI usb PIC-programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AEI USB PIC programmer is a copy of the [Brenner8](http://www.sprut.de/electronic/pic/projekte/brenner8/index.htm), which is controlled by a program called [US-Burn](http://www.sprut.de/electronic/soft/usburn/usburn.htm). The linux version can be downloaded from:-

http://www.sprut.de/electronic/soft/usburn/linux/usburn_linux.htm.

Comment: It was helpful thx